# How to show pop ups in lightning, when a custom object is updated?

Tags: lightning, mobile, app, popup, component

I have a requirement to show pop up when our custom object is updated depending on the update happpened. 
i.e. if on of the field say Screening result=Good and ContactVerified= true then I have to show popup saying "Screening result is good, go ahead with further steps"
The page where popup is expected is a lightning page.

This popup should also appear in SF 1 mobile app as well.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. When asking a question, it's a good idea to provide the code/markup that you've developed so far. Doing this helps to show that you've made a good-faith attempt to solve your problem on your own, can help people identify any mistakes or red flags, and generally improves the quality of the answers you'll get. The goal of this site is not to be a code-writing service, but rather to help you become a better programmer by helping you overcome _specific_ problems. You should [edit] your question to include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean lightning record page, then I would suggest you to fire a platform event and subscribe to that event in a lightning component. When you receive the event, that lightning component should create pop up component dynamically (use $A.createComponent). The parent lightning component should have nothing in it's markup. Basically even if you drag and drop the component it should not render anything. it should create the pop up component only if the component receives that particular platform event and should display the pop up then. Use lightning:empApi to subscribe to platform events from a lightning component.

Comment: Thanks @Manjunatha VP. This looks like a appropriate approach. I will try this and share.

Comment: Yes please do share.

Comment: Hi Manjunath, I did create a platform events and subscribing from a lightning component. But looks like nothing is happening. Its not the pop up component but its just to test if that compenent triggers or not. but somehow not working, I am new to lightning, can you please help me with a sample popup component, which i can test with events. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you please send me the code. Also from where are you firing the platform event. Are you firing it in before or after insert triggers or before or after update trigger?

Comment: I was firing from process builder, but later did from trigger and checked from debug statements that its being fired successfully. But from the subscribing lightning component I dont see any response. Here is the link to subscribing lightning component which I used as is -  https://rajvakati.com/2018/12/28/platform-events-subscribe-using-lightning-component/

Comment: And I used my event object name using above code in the link

Comment: If you are using as it is, as mentioned in the link, then when the component is not even subscribing to the event until you press the "Subscribe" button, so call the onsubscribe function in the doinit method and then from workbench or developer console, do an update to the record and then check.

Comment: I called " c.subscribe" from the init method and then updated record from workbench, nothing happened. Is there anythign that i can change in component or make it simple just to display some message when event is fired. thanks.

Comment: Whenever the event is received use an alert in JavaScript, this will notify you